# Appium Native App Automation in C#-

Tags: c#, android, appium, ui-automation

An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code.
            Code is not finidng even a single element. could you please advice how to rectify this.

```
 AppiumDriver<IWebElement> driver;
                    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                    capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
                    capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Windows");
                    capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
                    capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");

                    capabilities.SetCapability("appPackage", "smartscaffolder.sitemanager.lyndon");
                    capabilities.SetCapability("appActivity", "smartscaffolder.sitemanager.lyndon.MainActivity");

                    driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

                    Thread.Sleep(5000);       

                    var clearuname = driver.FindElementByClassName("//android.widget.Image");
                    clearuname.Click();

                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    var el = driver.FindElementsByClassName("android.widget.EditText").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Image[1]"));`

This is code in java but I am assuming it is very similar in C#.

It is possible that you are getting this exception due to not being able to find a singular element. You can verify this by going

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.Image[1]"));
```

Notice the `s` in the `findElements` command.

I would recommend using the appium inspector and copying the xml of the page and then using a site such as [this](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) to verify you are getting a specific element.

If this does not work please include more information in your description such as: Appium version, android OS, and a `glist` of the appium log as it is very useful in diagnosing what the issue is.